# How to use a decorator for all admin views

Tags: python, django

I have a decorator which allows requests to get through only from a whitelisted set of IPs. How to I plug it in for all admin views with minimal change in code.

Here's the decorator.

```
def allow_by_ip(view_func):
    def authorize(request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_ip = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
        if user_ip in WHITELIST_IP_INTERNAL_ADMIN:
            return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return Response({'error': 'Not allowed!'}, status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
    return authorize
```

Comment: Did you try to use this as middleware? Check this blog post [link](http://blackglasses.me/2014/08/04/django-admin-restriction-middleware/)

Answer (score 1):

It is better and clearer to create custom middleware for django, where you will check requested path and, if it is an admin path your code will check the IP against of whitelist.

You can make a file like whitelist_middleware.py:

```
class WhitelistIPMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
       request_ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR', None)
       if request_ip not in WHITELIST_IP_INTERNAL_ADMIN:
          raise Http403 # or 404, if you want
       return None
```

That you place that file into the same directory with settings.py (by default, if you have no special directory for middlewares). And after that add it into `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` tuple in the settings.py, of course.

Another way is to user [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/). But it may require some refactoring, which could be painful. So I think, it's better to user middleware. It is a clean and simple way to add some special handling for a bunch of views.